# Urlparse and '\n'

Tags: python, urlparse

I have:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
s = "http://google.com" + "\n" # this line is read from file, when I loop over file's lines 
urlparse(s)
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='google.com\n', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Is this correct? Shouldn't "\n" be removed during parsing? Or I'm just using this function incorrectly or I'm missing some argument/parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing text lines, always use `str.rstrip()` to remove the trailing CRLF. This will also help you in your case:

```
for line in open('file.txt'):
    line = line.rstrip()  # strip the trailing CRLF
    # do what you need with the line
```